# reference data member in const object remains modifiable unlike non-reference data members

Tags: c++, c++20

Why is it that reference data members seem to escape the constness of their encapsulating objects?

```
struct A {
    int &i;
    int j;
};

int i = 0;
const A a{i, 0};

a.j = 1; // compile error. j is read-only
a.i = 0; // fine even though a is const.

// same is true for const reference to A
const auto& ar = a;
ar.j = 1;
ar.i = 0; // compiles
```

The following link offers an explanation but their scenario is a bit different (template type expansion seemingly causing it):

https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/07/13/the-incredible-const-reference-that-isnt-const/

What is the most efficient way to enforce constness over `&i`?

Answer (score 3):

Your misunderstanding is because

## East const worst const west const best const

`const int&` is misleading.  It should be `int const&`. If you **always** put `const` on the right, C++ makes more sense.  `const` on the left is confusing.

`int&const` is not a thing; references are already "top level const" because they cannot be reseated.

So adding `const` to `int&` doesn't give you `int const&`, it does **nothing**.

An `int const&` is better called a reference-to-const, not a const-reference.

---

What should you do?  Don't mix references and non-references in the same struct or class.

The assignment and copy semantics of reference and non-reference variables and members are not compatible.  A struct with all references has reference semantics; one with all values has value semantics.  And one with both is simply insane.

```
struct bob {
  int & a;
  int & b;
};
```

this behaves like a reference.  Copy constructor duplicates what is referenced.  Assignment modifies the referenced objects themselves.

```
struct alice {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

this behaves like a value.  Copy and assignment changes the values themselves.

A `bob const` is nearly indistinguishable from a `bob`, just as a `int&const` "is the same thing as a `int&`".

If `bob` propogated const via accessors, then:

```
struct bob {
  int const& geta()const{return a;}
  int& geta(){return a;}
private:
  int & a;
};
```

safe, right?  No.

```
const bob b0=whatever;
bob b1=b0;
b1.geta()=7;
```

`b1` breaks your supposedly "safe" `b0`, because copy is from const, and copy to a non-const is legal, so `b1` has access to the references in `b0`.

The way you solve this is via:

```
struct const_bob {
  int const&a;
  int const&b; 
};
```

like `std::vector<???>::const_iterator`.

There really isn't another way that works well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought const int& and int const& were semantically the same. I wanted to avoid making the members of the struct const. Because I want some objects of A to have constness over all their members and some to have none. But there seems to be no other way.

Comment: @kevin they are, but `const int&` is *confusing*, because naively it makes you think `const T` when `T` is `int&` is `const int&` when it is not.  `T const` when `T` is `int&` is `int&const`, which is `int&`, as the `&` part of the type cannot be mutated anyhow.  If you pretend *west const* is illegal, the C++ type system makes intuitive sense.  If you use it, it is confusing as all hell.

Answer (score 1):

Appropriate getters.

```
struct A {
    int& i() { return i_; }
    const int& i() const { return i_; }
    int j;

private:
    int &i_;
};
```